# 6 speed manual transmission is internally engaging in 2 gears?

Tags: mazda, miata

I was towing my Mazda Miata, I ran over tire tread in the road.  Tread jammed my rear wheels caused the car to drag and leave tire marks on the highway.  Had it looked at $ 400.00 , then the shop called , needs $ 1300 more to tear down transmission to tell me what is wrong ?  this just does not seems right.  I am new to the area, single female and alone.  I had it towed from there today. thoughts ?  thanks

Comment: If the transmission internals are damaged you would likely do better to find a used replacement than to pay a local mechanic to tear into it. Advise you seek out a dedicated miata forum in any case

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is your Miata? I'm going to guess it's probably newer than 2000? (I think they started putting the 6-speed in them around then). How many miles on the car? Was there any fluid leakage after the incident (that you noticed)?

Comment: Very important question: is there actually something wrong with the car now? Have you tried to run it and noticed that something was wrong? If your Miata was being towed, then it should have been in neutral. If it was in neutral, then I find it *very* hard to believe that something would have messed up the transmission al all since it's in a free-spinning state... Also, it's "extremely rare that a transmission can (even when damaged) engage 2 gears simultaneously." (Quote from my buddy who's been a mechanic for ~20 years.)

Comment: Sadly, many shops will lie and say that services are needed that are not. But many shops are also completely trustworthy... make is a pretty dicey industry unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the transmissions configuration.. 
As you say you ran over a tyre.. If you literally ran right over it then its possible that the tyre traveled under the gearbox first damaging it, possibly impacting the gear selector mechanism. So, this would be like trying to force a gear change without the clutch which could certainly damage the gearbox's internal parts, especially as the transmission will have been under load at the time of impact with the tyre.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Mazda 6-speed manual tranny has the shifter directly mounted to the transmission so there's no external linkage.

Comment: By the way, SE has been bumping this question every month for 3 years. It does that because it believes there are no good answers, because no one has upvoted any.  Upvote an answer and it'll stop doing that :)